# Priority queue using heap (Whats wrong with my code?)

Tags: c++, queue, heap

I am doing an assignment priority queue using heap
these are instructions for every commands

1. Add element create an element with the id an priority given
   add the element to the queue
   produce no output for this command
2. Delete element deleted the element with specified id from the queue
   produce no output for this command
3. Reset priority locate the element with the specified id within the priority queue change the element’s priority to the value requested produce no output for this command
4. read query the highest priority element from the queue
   print the current (overall total) command number, the element id and priority on
   standard output, followed by a newline, as follows:
   i.e.: at command number 5087, top of queue is element 99 with priority 1
   do not print the "read command number" at this time
5. Pop query the highest priority element and remove it from the queue
   produce no output for this command
6. finalize successively read and pop all elements remaining in the queue
   provide output consistent with the read command for each remaining element

---

```
void pop(int heapSize){
  heap[0]=heap[heapSize-1]; //overwrite
  heapSize--;
  heapifyDown(0);
}

void heapifyDown(int insert){
  int nextStep = insert;
  right = (insert + 1)*2;
  left=right-1;
  if (left<heapSize){
    nextStep=left;
  }
  if((right<heapSize)&&(heap[right].priority<heap[left].priority)){
    nextStep=right;
  }
  while(heap[nextStep].priority < heap[insert].priority){
    swap(heap[nextStep, heap[insert]]);
    insert=nextStep;
  }
  right=()insert+1)*2;
  leaft=right-1;
  if(left<heapSize){
    nextStep=left;
  }
  if((right<heapSize)&&heap[right].priority<heap[left].priority){
    nextStep=right;
  }
}

void deleteElement(heapElement, int element, int heapSize){ 

  int index; // to remember the deleted node's position
  for(int i=1; i <heapSize; i++){

    if (heap[i] == element){
        heap[i]=NULL;        
        index = i; // position of removed element;
        break;
    }
  }

  // move the last element(A[num_items_in_array]) in array to the
  // position of removed element; heapify up/down according to
  // priority
}

void reset(int element, int newP){
  for(int i=1; i <heapSize; i++){
    if (heap[i] == element){
        heap[i].priority = newP;
        heapifyDown(heap[i], newP);
        heapifyUp(heap[i], newP);
    }
  }
}

void read(){
  if(!heap[].empty()){
    cout << heap[0];
  }
}

void finalize(){
  for(i=1; i<heapSize; i++){
    cout << heap[i];
    heap[i]=NULL;
  }   
}

int main()
{
  int case, counter;
  elment_priority node;
  while(counter < 1000){
    cin >> case;
    cin >> node.element;
    cin >> node.priority;

    int addSum, deleteSum, resetSum, readSum, popSum,
        finalizeSum, totalSum=0;
    switch(case) {
        case 1:
            addElement(heapElement,node.element, heapSize);
            addSum++;
        case 2:
            deleteElement(heapElement,node.element, heapSize);
            deleteSum++:
        case 3:
            reset(node.element, node.priority);
            resetSum++;
        case 4:
            read();
            readSum++;
        case 5:
            pop();
            popSum++;
        case 6:
            finalize();
            finalizeSum++;
        default: 
            cout<<"Cannot Process Command :"
                + case + node.element
                + node.priority + ": wrong command";
    }
  }

  cout << "\n";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "================================================================";
  cout << addSum << "total add commands processed.\n";
  cout << deleteSum << "total delete commands processed.\n";
  cout << resetSum << "total reset commands processed.\n";
  cout << readSum << "total read commands processed.\n";
  cout << popSum << "total pop commands processed.\n";
  cout << finalizeSum << "total finalize commands processed.\n";
  cout << totalSum << "total commands processed.\n";

}
```

Comment: Could you post output?  It looks pretty close to me...

Comment: Have you used your debugger?   Non-debugging of code on SO is a reason for closing out a question.